# Getting error while converting model into pb file for android

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am getting this error:

```
frozen_graph = freeze_graph(K.get_session(), output_names=[model.output.op.name])

TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

I am using tensorflow version 1.15.0 with keras 2.0.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did not include the full code but let me guess, your have an import statement that looks like this:

`from tensorflow.tools import freeze_graph`

It should be:

`from tensorflow.tools.freeze_graph import freeze_graph`

This is because the `freeze_graph` function actually lives in a module that is called `freeze_graph` as well. The import statement you used import the whole module. When your code reaches the `freeze_graph` part is, quite accurately, errors out saying modules are not callable :)