# I found the error 'module object is not callable'

Tags: python

[image: error is coming in this code]

**while running this code, I got stuck over here...can someone please help me?**

Comment: Please post the code as part of the question and not as image

Comment: Please take a few minutes to read this. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question#:~:text=You%20should%20not%20post%20code,order%20to%20reproduce%20the%20problem.

Comment: https://colab.research.google.com/github/Tony607/tf_jetson_nano/blob/master/Step1_Colab_TensorRT.ipynb#scrollTo=PVik2KNNNll8....you can check over here

Comment: The error message is telling you exactly what the problem is: you are importing a module and then attempting to call it as if it were a function. Presumably you intended to import (or call) something from within that module?

Comment: This question is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/60079657/8321664

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting error while converting model into pb file for android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60079657/getting-error-while-converting-model-into-pb-file-for-android)

Comment: Actually your IDE already flags the line as suspicious, therefore the red waveline....

Comment: If the colab page is something you copied, note that it defines its own function called "freeze_graph", and that is not the same thing as the module you're importing and it's not the same function as the one defined in the `freeze_graph` module, either.

Answer (score 0):

Im not familiar with tensorflow, but could you try:

```py
from tensorflow.python.tools.freeze_graph import freeze_graph
```

?

Comment: yes i tried this, but this is not working

Comment: Ah damn, it was just a guess

Comment: Wait that's weird, its the correct answer on the duplicate question